# How can i get the current cell references from a formula using java p o i ? I want to update them accordingly

Tags: java, apache-poi

for example there is formula as "VLOOKUP($B2,'03 meest recente 
gegevens'!$A:$V,5,0)"

I want to drag this formula upto a certain row in order to do so i need 
the current row position and add one to it $B2 to $B3 and so on
whenever i am calling the method copyFormula it is copying but the formula 
is getting changed for ex. VLOOKUP($B2,'03 meest recente 
gegevens'!$A:$V,5,0) change to VLOOKUP($B3,'03 meest recente 
gegevens'!A:V,5,0)
you can see "$" symbol is changeing.
So i have created another method dragFormula() in which i am using regex to 
get the row number and increasing it by 1 for every row 
Is there any other way around to solve this because  what i have done is ... 
seems pretty static because lets say if you want to drag below formula
=DATE(LEFT(G2,4),MID(G2,5,2),RIGHT(G2,2))
the G2 needs to get adusted acording to the row and my dragFormula(args..) method can do that ..... However this can be achived by the copyFormula(args..) method .. I am confused sometimes copyFormula method is needed and sometimes dragFormula method works 
how to solve this Help ... And THANKS in advance

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaRenderer;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.Area3DPtg;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.AreaPtg;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.Ptg;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.RefPtgBase;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DragFormula {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DragFormula from = new DragFormula();
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\mayank.kumar01\\Desktop\\Project\\Mailmerge\\format_mailmerge_20140527(template).xlsx");
        try{
            OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
            XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
            CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("F2");
            Row oldRow = sheet2.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
            Row newRow = sheet2.createRow(2);
            Cell oldCell = oldRow.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
            Cell newCell = newRow.createCell(cellReference.getCol());
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
            String oldFormula = oldCell.getCellFormula();
            System.out.println("oldFolmula : "+oldFormula);
            from.copyFormula(sheet2, oldCell, newCell, 1);
            from.dragFormula(oldCell, sheet2, 25);
            workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(file));;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    private void copyFormula(Sheet sheet, Cell org, Cell dest,int inc) {

        if (org == null || dest == null || sheet == null 
                || org.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
            return;
        if (org.isPartOfArrayFormulaGroup())
            return;
        String formula = org.getCellFormula();
        XSSFEvaluationWorkbook workbookWrapper = 
                XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((XSSFWorkbook) sheet.getWorkbook());
        Ptg[] ptgs = FormulaParser.parse(formula, workbookWrapper, FormulaType.CELL
                , sheet.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(sheet));

       for (int i=0;i<ptgs.length;i++) {
            if (ptgs[i] instanceof RefPtgBase) // base class for cell references
            {
                RefPtgBase ref = (RefPtgBase) ptgs[i];
                if (ref.isColRelative())
                    ref.setColumn(ref.getColumn());
                if (ref.isRowRelative())
                    ref.setRow(ref.getRow()+inc);
            }
            else if (ptgs[i] instanceof Area3DPtg) // base class for range references
            {
                Area3DPtg ref = (Area3DPtg) ptgs[i];
            }
        }


        formula = FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString(workbookWrapper, ptgs);
        System.out.println("Modified Formula : "+formula);
        dest.setCellFormula(formula);
    }

public void dragFormula(Cell oldCell,XSSFSheet sheet,int uptoRow){
    String formula = "VLOOKUP($B2,'03 meest recente gegevens'!$A:$V,5,0)";
    String regex = "(\\$)?([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+)"; // creating the regex
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);       
    int rowIndex = oldCell.getRowIndex()+1;
    int inc = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<=uptoRow;i++){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
        Matcher match = p.matcher(formula);
        if(match.find()){                          // matching the pattern   
            formula = formula.replaceFirst(match.group(3),((Integer)(Integer.parseInt(match.group(3))+inc)).toString());
        }
        Cell newCell = row.createCell(oldCell.getColumnIndex());
        newCell.setCellFormula(formula);
        System.out.println("Modified Formula"+formula);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is you input please share your input file with dummy data

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow but how can i share a file here

Comment: edit you question and attach a file or simply google it

Comment: [Area3DPtg](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/Area3DPtg.html) is `HSSF` only. Try [Area3DPxg](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/Area3DPxg.html) `else if (ptgs[i] instanceof Area3DPxg)` and then [AreaPtgBase.setFirstColRelative(false)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/AreaPtgBase.html#setFirstColRelative%28boolean%29) and  [AreaPtgBase.setLastColRelative(false)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/AreaPtgBase.html#setLastColRelative%28boolean%29). Not tested, only a guess.

Comment: AreaPtgBase does not have any setFirstColRelative(boolean b) method or can explain a bit more exactly what to do

Comment: Naa not working

Comment: It is not a instance of Area3DPxg.

Comment: Maybe `else if (ptgs[i] instanceof AreaPtgBase)`?

Comment: yes it is a instance of AreaPtgBase. i have set the cols false but still it not preserving the $

Comment: Just tested. Your `copyFormula` works fine for me using `apache poi` **version 3.16 (latest stable)**. Please upgrade. Changes needed: `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;` and `... org.getCellTypeEnum() != CellType.FORMULA ...` since `Cell.getCellType()` is deprecated. Produces: `oldFolmula : VLOOKUP($B2,'03 meest recente gegevens'!$A:$V,5,0)`
`Modified Formula : VLOOKUP($B3,'03 meest recente gegevens'!$A$1:$V$1048576,5,0)`

Comment: i think you are right thanks Axel. It is working fine now